# How to remove suffix in wicket web page

Tags: java, wicket

I have created a web page in wicket and mounted it. The url looks like so:

```
http://localhost:8080/app/page?5
```

Is there an option to remove the number at the end which is still incrementing?

I also mount this page: `mountPage("page", Page.class);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This number appears because your page is stateful. If you want to avoid this you'll need to create stateless pages.

Read this wiki entry for more details:
https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/stateless-pages.html

Answer (score 0):

You can disables the sufix by changing RequestCycleStrategy settings to [ONE_PASS_RENDER](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/settings/IRequestCycleSettings.html) You can change RequestCycleStrategy in your WicketApplication's init() method.